# c# process/cmd output parsing to variables

Tags: c#, process, cmd, progress-bar

I'm making gui to rtmp-plugin that is commandline program. I need way to read output data from cmd program to three variables: downloaded, time and done. 
In cmd output is exsample "3000 kb / 12 sec (12%)" without "". How I can get 3000 to downloaded variable without kb and 12 to time without sec and 12 to done without () and %. My code to run cmd process below.

```
    int downloaded, time, done;
    var proc = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "Data/yle-dl/yle-dl.exe",
                Arguments = "-o pasila.flv http://areena.yle.fi/tv/1755554 --rtmpdump rtmpdump.exe ",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                CreateNoWindow = false
            }
        };

        proc.Start();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can catch program output and parse values using regex. Note that you should also catch error output as it happens often, that normal output is handled as an error.

```
 Process process = new Process();
 process.StartInfo.FileName = "Data/yle-dl/yle-dl.exe";
 process.StartInfo.Arguments = "-o pasila.flv http://areena.yle.fi/tv/1755554 --rtmpdump rtmpdump.exe ";
 process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
 process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
 process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
 process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
 process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
 process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(ReadOutput);
 process.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(ReadOutput);

 process.Start();
 process.BeginOutputReadLine();
 process.BeginErrorReadLine();

 process.WaitForExit();


  private static void ReadOutput(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
  {
     if (e.Data != null)
     {
       Match m = Regex.Match(e.Data, "(\\d+)[^0-9]*(\\d+)[^0-9]*(\\d+)[^0-9]");
       if (m.Success)
       {
        textBox1.Text = m.Result("$1");
        string time = m.Result("$2");
        string percent = m.Result("$3");
       }
     }
  }
```

Comment: @user1992794 that's correct, `textBox1.Text = m.Result("$1");`

Comment: I get error "The name 'm' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: @user1992794 see my edit and read about scopes http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: now i get error "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property "

Comment: @user1992794 mate, you will get all possible errors until you understand what you are doing. My code is working and I don't know how you used or changed it.

Answer (score 0):

If there is already some kind of output from the commandline you can catch it by using [BeginOutputReadLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.diagnostics.process.beginoutputreadline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Otherwise you can add the assembly to your program references and access the (if exists) variable that the program uses to indicate your state.